# Is DIC only good for "high level" services?

Tags: dependency-injection

I have been reading several articles to understand how DIC should be used. I understand that using the DIC as a service locator is not really what you should be wanting to do, if the application needs to be testable and such.

So is it correct to assume that a DIC is best used to inject, what I would like to call, "high level objects" (services) into other objects only? (e.g. A Mailer, PDF printer, Database services....)

I don't see how a DIC can help me with scenarios where I need to create "detail" objects and then pass them to a "master" object to be processed. For example to create OrderItems and having the Order object process them further.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `DIC` stand for? Dependency Injection Container?

Comment: Your thoughts seem to be correct. Take a look at [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/)

Comment: The article looks interesting. Thank you for the link.